# Why does lightroom stop syncing to mobile?

Tags: lightroom, mobile, sync, hangs

**My Lightroom v2015.6.1 stops sync'ing frequently to Lightroom mobile.**

I have to close the desktop application and reopen it for synchronization to start again.  I'm sync'ing a fair amount of photos over a few days.

- I've checked my internet connection.
- I've restarted Lighroom, which fixes the problem temporarily

**Does anyone know why it stops so often?**

Comment: Check you've got enough storage at both ends (and for a bidirectional sync opeartion it wouldn't surprise me if it needed considerably more than the size of the  files).  Test what happens if your internet connection goes down momentarily -- it may not recover very well.

Comment: "Test what happens if your internet connection goes down momentarily -- it may not recover very well." - that was it.  I didn't think something so simple could be the cause, thanks!  Feel free to answer it.

Comment: I think this is very valid because I assumed Lightroom would have auto recovered from a downed internet connection, but it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes operations don't recover properly from a brief interruption in internet connection.  So it's worth checking whether such momentary glitches cause the process to hang.